# How to bind to a url in an object of array in vue js 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an array of items with the title, icon, and url for each item in the array. So what I want is when a user clicks an item, they should be taken to the url. How do I do this in the markup?

```
state: {

navigation: [
  
  {
    title: "Home",
    icon: "",
    url: "/"
},

  {
    title: "Pages",
    icon: "",
    url: "/pages"
},
```

]
}

```
<template>
<div class="w-40 h-full fixed bg-gray-800 b-t-white text-sm font-serif font-medium antialiased text-white pl-2 pt-4 z-20">
    <ul id="navigation">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in navigation" :key="'item'+index">
        <i v-if="item.subnav" class="icon" :class="{'ChevronLeftIcon' :!item.open, 'ChevronDownIcon' :item.open }"></i>
        <div class="title" @click="item.open = !item.open">{{item.title}}</div>
        <Dropdown v-if="item.subnav" :list="item" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Dropdown from './Dropdown.vue'
export default {
    components:{Dropdown},
computed:{
  navigation(){
    return this.$store.getters.navigation;
  }
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: For this purpose people often use dynamic routing: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Comment: How are you rendering these items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your rendered item element with `router-link` component and use `to` prop to navigate to the target url :

```html
<router-link :to="item.url">
  <!-- your element -->
</router-link>
```

Comment: When I try this I get the errors "item" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance & Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url'). Are there any solutions to fixing it? Or what could I be missing out on?

Comment: @DavidMaxwell That indicates your `<router-link :to="item.url">` was added outside the `<li v-for=(item, index) in navigation">` that you have in the question. The `v-for` declares the `item` property, and it's only available inside its context.